# If $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$ then show that $\dfrac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \omega \dfrac{d\omega}{d\theta}$.

Tags: derivatives, change-of-variable

Let $$ \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$$ show that **$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$** can be expressed as $$\omega\frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$$

My approach is as follows: $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\biggl(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\biggl)$$ if we substitute **$dt=\frac{d\theta}{\omega}$** then $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{\frac{d\theta}{\omega}}\biggl(\frac{d\theta}{\frac{d\theta}{\omega}}\biggl) = \frac{d(\omega)}{d\theta}\biggl({\frac{d\theta}{d\theta}\omega}\biggl) = \omega\frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$$

However, I have a feeling that this approach is mathematically incorrect. Hence I was wondering

what other approaches are there, with **mathematical rigor**.

Moreover, when changing variables of derivatives like this, be it first or second derivatives, are

there any general **rules** that apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express $\omega$ as a composite function $\omega=f(\theta(t))$

than use the chain rule

$$\frac{d \omega}{d t}=\frac{d \omega}{d \theta}\frac{d \theta}{d t}=\omega\frac{d \omega}{d \theta}$$

Comment: I've added the solution to my answer. As you can see it is different from your approach.

Comment: It is, and much simpler and straight forward.

Comment: Is $f$ really doing anything here?  I feel like this is similar to the other answer, but leaving out some of the early details.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{\mathrm d^2\theta}{\mathrm dt^2}
&=& \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt} \\
&=& \dfrac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dt} \\
&=& \dfrac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm d\theta} \dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt} \\
&=& \dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt} \dfrac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm d\theta} \\
&=& \omega \dfrac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm d\theta} \\
\end{array}$$